# Laptop connected to roscore host, does not receive messages

Tags: ros, pandaboard, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I was having some problems setting up my wifi network with a laptop and a pandaboard. The pandaboard starts its own wifi network through hostapd and the laptop connects to that network. The ROS_MASTER_URI is correctly set (ROS_HOSTNAME too, to '192.168.2.1', but I'm not sure it's still required) to http://192.168.2.1:11311 (Pandaboard) and the laptop can indeed communicate with the roscore (doing for example rostopic list gives me the correct list of currently active topics).

However if I do the following command on the laptop :

```
rostopic pub -r 1 /test std_msgs/String hello
```

and

```
rostopic echo /test
```

on the pandaboard, no messages are received. If I switch 'roles', no messages are received either. If I send and echo on the pandaboard, it does display messages. If I send and echo on the laptop, no messages are displayed.

If I connect both to my home network and set the ROS_MASTER_URI to its local IP everything works fine, but I don't always have such a network available... Is there something wrong with my hostapd network?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32572/laptop-connected-to-roscore-host,-does-not-receive-messages/) by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1909 on 2012-04-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you check all the steps at:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup

Also i had some trouble with some entries in the /etc/hosts file since the entries there usually overwrite the information from the DNS/DHCP Server. If you have some entries there, you can make a backup of your /etc/hosts file and delete every entry except the following:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
```

At least this was the cause for a similar problem in a network with non-static IP addresses....

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2012-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on 2012-04-25**:
Thanks, that seems to have helped me.